# What is the minimal area of a fully-fledged Dyson sphere?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

A [Dyson sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere) is a hypothetical megastructure made up of a finite number of thin sun-shades in free-fall orbit around a central star. The goal is to harvest as much of the sun's radiation power as possible. In this regard, let's agree that a Dyson sphere is "fully-fledged" iff all rays emanating from the star's center must intersect one of the sphere's shades (at all times). Suppose in addition that all shades must keep a distance of at least $R$ from the star's center (in order not to evaporate, say). **What is the minimal surface area of shade-material that must be allocated in creating such a fully fledged Dyson-sphere?**

To have my question well-posed, I should briefly discuss the rules of motion in orbital mechanics. For the occasion, let me state them as follows: a single sun-shade $S(t)\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a relatively open subset of a sphere $\partial B(0,d) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ which is contained within a ribbon $r(\varepsilon,C)\subset B(0,d)$ of a (small) thickness $\varepsilon$ around a great circle $C$ of the sphere $\partial B(0,d).$ $S(t)$ changes with time $t$ through rigid rotation along the great circle $C$ with rotation speed $v=1/\sqrt{d}$.
As such, the question of the minimal required surface area $A_{\varepsilon}$ retains a dependence on the thickness-parameter $\varepsilon$. Obviously, $\varepsilon \mapsto A_{\varepsilon}$ is a decreasing function so that I'm ready to ask my question: what might $A:=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0+} A_{\varepsilon}$ might be?

Allow me also to briefly discuss a few obvious bounds: clearly we always have that $A\geq 4\pi R^2$. On the other hand, by arranging a number of circular ribbons in the way of the picture below(*), it is clear that $A \leq 2\pi^2 R^2$: in this setup, at all time around 36% of the shade-area is in the shadow cast by other shades.

[image]
Picture courtesy by [wikipedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pokrovsky_shell.png)

(*) The picture does not do a *perfect* job of depicting the configuration that I'm referring to. Specifically, the ribbons in the picture approach each-other closest at distinct locations in space, while I rather am referring to a configurations where these ribbons are great circles going from a shared north pole to a shared south pole (with slightly different radii to avoid collision at these poles) along the meridians suggested by this pair of poles.

Comment: For the area of a sphere $A=\pi d^2=4\pi r^2$

Comment: "which *is contained within* a ribbon $r(\epsilon,C)$" - so it doesn't have to be constant width? Then you can cut out the shaded areas on each strip (at least as $\epsilon \to 0$) and therefore $4\pi R^2$ becomes your minimum.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: unfortunately that doesn't work. You forget that the screens have to orbit around the star with a certain velocity. By your method, you may arrange the ribbons at one given time so that they completely cover the star, but due to their motion unwanted openings will arise at (most) other times.

Comment: Seems to me that having screens be in the shadow of other screens is an inefficient use of space. Also, multiple screens must be constructed at different distances, and area grows with the square of distance. Also, not all rays are captured. To capture all rays in all directions at all times you must have what appears to be a spherical enclosing, from the stars perspective looking outward.  Seems to me if you put all of this together, the natural solution minimizing area is to have a minimally sized sphere around the star.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Such a sphere is unstable. If its equator moved according to orbital mechanics, then the poles would not, so the rest of the sphere would need to exert forces in the poles to stop them from moving like orbital mechanics would dictate. This introduces stress to the structure, and it would break.